# Remove duplicated elements in a row and find the ratio for number of elements

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data frame like this, it contain 3 or more characters separated by comma (,) I want to remove the row if it contain same characters.

```
x <-c(1,2,2,4,5)
y <-c("a,a,a","a,a,b,c","b,c,a","b,b,b,b","a,b,b,c")
df<-data.frame(x,y)
```

following code is my try,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(y) %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(y) > 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(countX = n())
  summarise(x, countX, y = toString(y), CountY = n(), rat = CountY/countX)
```

I want calculate the number of distinct x values, number of elements in a row of y and then calculate the ratio between these

desired output is

```
x <-c(2,2,5)
cx <-c(2,2,1)
y <-c("a,a,b,c","b,c,a","a,b,b,c")
cy <-c(4,3,4)
rat <- c(4/2,3/2,4/1)
df<-data.frame(x,cx,y,cy,rat)
```

Comment: Can you explain how do you get `cx` as 2, 2 and 1?

Comment: cx calculate number of same x values. here 2 repeated two times therefore all 2 value set the count as 2. if its count is 3 then 3 set for all element 2. 5 occurs one time therefore it count is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are trying to do something like this :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(), 
         y1 = y) %>%
  add_count(x, name = 'cx') %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(y1) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(across(c(x, cx, y), first), 
            cy = n(), 
            rat = cy/cx, 
            n = n_distinct(y1)) %>%
  filter(n > 1) %>%
  select(-row, -n)

#     x    cx     y      cy   rat
#  <dbl> <int> <chr>   <int> <dbl>
#1     2     2 a,a,b,c     4   2  
#2     2     2 b,c,a       3   1.5
#3     5     1 a,b,b,c     4   4
```

Comment: I think you can understand my requirement based on above comment

Comment: Yes Its correct but I want y column also. so how can I modify it

Comment: if my characters are like this "a_a, b_b,a_c_b", separate_rows function first time read underscore for comma?

Comment: In `separate_rows` you can specify the `sep` argument. `tidyr::separate_rows(y1, sep = ",")`

Comment: One more thing when I run this for my actual data it still group my row, when I use ungroup() it still remain is there any method to omit that concatenate.

Comment: The data should not be grouped after `summarise`. You can add `ungroup` after `filter`. `filter(n > 1) %>% ungroup %>%  select(-row, -n)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225448/discussion-between-isuru-and-ronak-shah).